# Custom FileInput on card - Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to add a custom file selection on the card using Bootstrap:

I try this:

```
<style>
label {
   cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-input-image {
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
}
</style>


<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <input type="file" id="id_img_1" name="id_img_1" class="custom-input-image">
    <label for="id_img_1" class="hover-shadow-lg hover-translate-y-n3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <!-- Image content-->
          <div>
            <div>
              <h4 class="mb-1"><i class="camera-icon"></i></h4>
              <small>Select file...</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  [...more cards..]
</div>
```

It gets the following effect:
[image]

I need this:
[image]

Adding a label to a card causes the card to shrink. How to get full length of card with added file selection.

Comment: Have you tried giving the card the class `w-100` which should tell it to take 100% of the possible width (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used font-awesome icons just as a placeholder icon, but you can try something like this:

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.custom-input-image {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row g-2 mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <input type="file" name="" id="" class="custom-input-image">
        <div class="card p-4 border border-3">
          <i class="fas fa-camera fa-2x"></i>
          <label for="">Select file</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <input type="file" name="" id="" class="custom-input-image">
        <div class="card p-4 border border-3">
          <i class="fas fa-camera fa-2x"></i>
          <label for="">Select file</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <input type="file" name="" id="" class="custom-input-image">
        <div class="card p-4 border border-3">
          <i class="fas fa-camera fa-2x"></i>
          <label for="">Select file</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```